# Android loading an image as layout backgroud crashes the App

Tags: android, image, layout, crash

I am using a 169.7 KB png image as a backgroung for my main layout. But application crashes during inflating the layout. If i reduces the image size then app is working fine.

Below is the crash statement:

> 06-17 17:42:47.252: E/AndroidRuntime(1041): Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

169.7 KB is not a large size image, so why it is crashing?

Can anyone help me to debug the issue?

Comment: maybe the image file could be corrupted

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @jerisalan: hmmm...but image is not corrupted...opening fine

Comment: Is there a chance that you can use a ninepatch (see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) instead?

Comment: @Maria Neumayer: I can use that but what's the reason behind using the 9-patch image as a background for this particular issue?

Comment: That kind of image should take around 4 MB in RAM, assuming it's RGB and not ARGB. If it's ARGB, it'll take around 5 MB of memory, the formula being (width*height*colorspace) for the memory in bytes. Is there anything else in your layout like images, videos etc?

Comment: The image probably wouldn't have to be that big. Using a fixed size background is always bad because there are phones with different aspect ratios. If it's a pattern that's repeating you could also just create a small png and set it in repeat mode (see XmlBitmap here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)

Comment: yep...i have total of 14 images including the layout background...no video...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the memory you allocated for the emulator while creating it in the Android AVD.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Max VM application heap size = 24....but if increasing the VM is a solution, then i disagree with this solution because the image i am using is not a VERY BIG SIZE IMAGE

Comment: increasing the VM size from 24 to 32 solves the issue but how can i debug the issue...may be there is a memory leak or some other problem...may be i am not following the best practice???

Answer (score 0):

The file size of the image is not relevant. What matters is the bitmap size (width x height x depth).